# My app keep deny the access to contacts iOS - Swift

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, cncontact

I have a view when it get loaded it will check first the permission to access the contacts if it's Authorized, NotDetermined or Denied .. the code at first time will go with NotDetermined so it will call function to ask for access .. the problem is here in this function :

```
private func requestContactsAccess() {
    //store = CNContactStore()

    store.requestAccessForEntityType(.Contacts) {granted, error in
        if granted {
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
                self.accessGrantedForContacts()
                return
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Now the app never ask for access to Contacts , I don't know why, it will select the permission as denied by its self .

I don't know if the problem with the code or the simulator because this work for other people .

Note : when I go to the settings of the sim , Setteings > Privacy > Contacts .. I find nothing ! just saying : 'Applications that have requested access to your contacts will appear here' . which mean the app never ask for it !

Any help ?

Comment: Did you not deny it in a previous attempt? iOS remembers it and doesn't ask again. You can try deleting the app from the device or simulator and running it again to see if that changes things.

Comment: does it need a info.plist request like location or bluetooth?

Comment: @jcaron This only the VC that ask for this access and I try to delete the app from the simulator and also I try another simulator model, but still same thing

Comment: @Ondrej no it doesn't

Comment: still need help

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if this is your problem but if you're running your app on iOS 10 Simulator you need to provide a "usage description" for accessing private information like Contacts (camera, camera roll, etc.).

Open your Info.plist and add a new entry and you will see new "Privacy - ..." settings.
[image: Privacy Settings]

Select "Privacy - Contacts Usage Description" and type in a usage description. See if this helps.

When run you should see the grant access popup with your usage description.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

First time when code executed, popup appears for permission of accessing contact list. Which button you tapped on that popup? (Allow or Don't Allow) ?

I think you have unintentionally tapped don't allow. Please go to Settings ->  -> Allow  to access Contacts -> Set switch to YES.

Comment: @zizoo you can also try resetting your simulator to check default behavior.

Comment: First , Thank you.. second, I did not select Don't Allow because in the question I mentioned that the app always go to NotDetermined case not denied then it will call this method to request the access , this method by default not asking for access it will chose the Don't Allow choice , that's my problem, Then after that the access will be denied because of this method