# IOS Objective-c - Getting contacts not working - No request prompt - Access denied

Tags: ios, objective-c, contacts, addressbook

I am using Objective-c to develop an app for iPad. I need to fetch the address book for the contacts. But I get no access request prompt and the access stays denied. The boolean "granted" is never true and the code to get the contacts array is never reached. Therefore the contacts array contactsArray stays empty.

Following is the code I am using:

```
-(void) fetchAllContacts
{
    contactsArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    CNContactStore *store = [[CNContactStore alloc] init];

    [store requestAccessForEntityType : CNEntityTypeContacts completionHandler : ^(BOOL granted, NSError * _Nullable error)
    {
        if (granted)
        {
             // Code to get the contacts array
             // contactsArray = ....
        }       
    }];
}
```

Any help?

Thank you

Comment: Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47019095/contacts-and-microphone-request-access-does-not-work-on-ios-9. It might help you.

Comment: At first your Info.plist file must include string value NSContactsUsageDescription (see Apple docs).

Comment: If you have already denied the permission iOS don't ask it again. You have to change it in the Settings app in the section of your app.

Comment: Thank you guys for your comments. @Eridana; a string value is added in NSContactsUsageDescription in my app. @ lorenzoliveto; My app is not visible in the Settings, actually the list is empty.

Comment: Hmm.. if you are using simulator, try to reset it and reinstall the app. Sometimes it really helps

Comment: @Eridana; I am testing my app directly on my iPad.

Comment: @BrianScherady, check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39327158/my-app-keep-deny-the-access-to-contacts-ios-swift, check your string in Info.plist, delete the app and install it again. If app is not visible in settings - something got wrong, and usually it's somewhere in .plist.

Comment: @BrianScherady I have tried your code on iPhone. 1) included Contacts.framework in "General -> Linked Frameworks & Libs" 2) Wrote value "Use your contacts" for key "Privacy - Contacts Usage Description" in .plist 3) wrote this code: import Contacts ...  let store = CNContactStore() store.requestAccess(for: .contacts) { (success, error) in  } 4) all is working.

Answer (score 1):

iOS will only present the modal access request prompt once. If you have denied the access the first time, the app will be unable to access it until the user changes the app's permissions in the iOS settings.

One option is to present a custom prompt saying access is denied with a button to navigate directly to the app settings page, using `UIApplicationOpenSettingsURLString` as an URL.

```
//objc
NSURL * url = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:UIApplicationOpenSettingsURLString];
[UIApplication.sharedApplication openURL:url];

//swift
if let url = URL(string: UIApplicationOpenSettingsURLString) {
    UIApplication.shared.openURL(url)
}
```

Comment: On my iPad in Settings -> Privacy -> Contacts under "Applications that have requested access to your contacts will appear here." there is nothing; no application is listed. Also I have never seen the prompt for request for access to the contacts. Furthermore, I deleted the app and restarted the iPad; it didn't help :(